# Python - IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, indentation

I'm using a python script to read the file but it shows an error as IndentationError. Here's my code

```
import subprocess

f = subprocess.Popen(['tail','-F','filepath'],\
         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:

    line = f.stdout.readline()

    if line == "":

    else:   

        print line
```

The error I'm getting is

```
else:   
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have nothing in your `if` block. If you want to avoid `if` block, either use `pass` in it or change the `if` condition

Comment: You might also want to take it easier with the empty lines and maybe google and read PEP8.

Comment: `if line != "": print line`, no need for an `else` at all

Comment: I don't want to print anything if the line is empty.

Comment: did you write any code inside if condition,

Comment: I you don't want to print anything if the line is empty, just check if the line is not empty and print your thing. the if else is superfluous. You can put `pass` in there to make the block actually empty but it's better to just fix your logic

Comment: It still prints the empty line in my data.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get around this would be to simply use:

```
if line != "":   

    print line
```

There's no need for an `else`.

Comment: And if one wants to skip writing code (for example for temporary development purposes) `pass` statement can be used.